# Issue on Adding Steps to jQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to add For steps and Value to jQuery UI Slider at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/98wXy/) to be look like this image
[image]

so I have 4 steps and he slider handler ONLY sits on one of those values(Not Between) I already tried this methis form jQuery UI documentation

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({ step: 4 });
var step = $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "step" );
$( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "step", 4 );
```

but it didn't work I also tried

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({  range: "min",
    min: 1000,
    max: 7000,
    value: 1000});
  });
```

again no success! can you please let me know how I can achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your step option setting should be the difference between values, not the number of steps:

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider").slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 1000,
        max: 7000,
        value: 1000,
        step:2000
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/98wXy/3/)**

Comment: Hi j08691, Thanks for reply I have to wait 10 min to accept your answer, meanwhile can you please also let me know how I can get the selected value? should I use change handler?

Comment: Look at the slide function in the fiddle. That will give you the value.